# Finder Window flash and disappears on unminimize

Tags: finder, macos

You can clearly see what's wrong with Finder in the GIF. When I click the Finder window, it appears to restore the window, and then it's gone. This usually happens after a while. It's very annoying, a quick fix is to **Force Quit** Finder, and I can restore those windows again.

1. There is only 1 Desktop spaces enabled
2. I have tried removing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`
3. My MacBook's version is macOS Sierra 10.12 latest version. If my memory is correct, I have seen this kind of problem before updating to Sierra (when I was using El Capitan)
4. I also tried removing the saved state from `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState`

[image: SysInfo]

[image: GIF]

Is there anyway to fix this? Please tell me if more information or log files are required. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's the gravitational field strength of the nearby earth mass. You should choose a wider orbit or a different - that is to say smaller - planet

Comment: @klanomath I'll change it to pluto and see if the window can withstand the gravitational pull. LoL, your comment made my day.

Comment: Have you tired disabling the animation for dock in preferences?

Comment: I have no animations but it happens to me for Terminal window sometimes. It is not about savedstate, but more about graphics. I could not find an reliable way to fix it -- just restart the application.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't happen to me anymore. I think some application that I was using interfered with the minimizing and maximizing.

Comment: I can reproduce this on macOS Mojave in other applications, not just Finder. This is beyond embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

After Finder window disappear on unminimize, press <kbd>Cmd-Ctrl-F</kbd>. The Finder window (and Safari window too where there is the same problem) reappear and go to full screen. Press <kbd>Cmd-Ctrl-F</kbd> one more time and it returns to normal size.

Comment: Thank you!  Not only can I recover my windows, but I also learned about cmd-ctrl-F.